# My site is accessible from my computer but not others?

Tags: networking, dns, apache-http-server, xampp

I am attempting to host a website onto the domain that I purchased from google domains (seanpatnode.com), I have tried several tutorials but I keep getting the same results. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I will give as much information as possible. I am using XAMPP 2.4 as the web server.

Here are relevant lines from my httpd.conf file: (please inform me if I left anything important out.)

```
ServerRoot "C:/xampp/apache"
Listen 80
ServerName localhost:80
<Directory />
AllowOverride none
Require all denied
</Directory>
# DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

These are the relevant lines from my httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/PhpProject"
ServerName seanpatnode.com
ServerAlias www.seanpatnode.com
<Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs/PhpProject">
AllowOverride All
Require all Granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

These are relevant lines from my hosts file located in: C:\WINDOWS\System32\drivers\etc

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   www.seanpatnode.com
```

I can see the webpage when I open www.seanpatnode.com from my own computer. However when I try to open it from another computer it says:

> This webpage is not available The server at www.seanpatnode.com can't
>   be found, because the DNS lookup failed. DNS is the network service
>   that translates a website's name to its Internet address. This error
>   is most often caused by having no connection to the Internet or a
>   misconfigured network. It can also be caused by an unresponsive DNS
>   server or a firewall preventing Google Chrome from accessing the
>   network.

Again, seanpatnode.com is the domain that I purchased from Google Domains. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `$ dig seanpatnode.com +short` This command makes a DNS query to return the `A` record of the provided domain. It did not return any response, so basically, you're able to access your domain because you defined a entry in your `hosts` file as `127.0.0.1   www.senpatnode.com`, but the DNS record hasn't been defined. Have you defined that DNS record a short time ago? Are you sure it is defined?

Comment: @nKn No, I have not defined any DNS records nor do I know what that implies. I'm searching how to define a DNS record now...

Comment: Basically you need to say to the world *where* your contents are located. So the most common way to do this is to find the *DNS editor* at Google Domains and define an `A` record pointing to your public IP. If you haven't got a static IP, then you might want to register a *Dynamic DNS* service like noip.com and then create a `CNAME` DNS register to that domain.

Comment: @nKn alright, I think I found what you were talking about on google domains. Is this it?[Click here to see image of google domains](http://s18.postimg.org/kygt58xy1/host.png) I actually have a static IP.

Comment: Yep. In the "Registered hosts" you create the DNS records, and the `IPv4 address` should be your static IP. Then, you'll need to forward port 80 on your router to the machine where you serve your HTML contents (for example, if your private IP address for that machine is `192.168.1.100`, you'd configure that). Also, check any firewall configuration you might have; otherwise, it should work.

Comment: @nkn I forwarded port 80 I think [Link to image of my port forward](http://s1.postimg.org/omrjtpbsf/ports.png)
I believe I have the the host name correct and my static IP is an IPv6 so I put that in there.

Comment: Seems ok to me. Bear in mind that DNS records take up to 1 day to propagate everywhere, so give it a time.

Comment: You can check out your router configuration by finding your public IP using something like http://whatismyipaddress.com/, then entering this address into a proxy server such as http://vectroproxy.com/. Once you have verified that the router and your internal network are correctly configured, you can then concentrate on the domain addressing (note that `ping` will tell you the IP address for a domain even if there is no reply).

Comment: @AFH When I ping on my computer I get a response from localhost. When I ping from another computer it says "ping request could not find the host" The address that I found on whatismyipaddress.com is the same one I used to create the DNS record.

Comment: You would need to run `ping` from the public internet, outside your router. If you can't do this easily, then from inside your network you can use something like https://www.whatismyip.com/dns-lookup/.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do three things:-

1. Make your web server accessible from the external internet: this means setting port forwarding in your router so that port 80 is mapped from the public internet to the machine where your web server is running, which must therefore be assigned a fixed address on your intranet.
2. You need a public IP address for your router, either by getting a fixed address from your ISP, or by using a Dynamic IP service (there are several free ones available).
3. Finally, you need to map your domain to the router's IP address, and Google as your domain registrar will provide the tools to do this, mapping your domain to either your fixed IP or the URL the Dynamic IP service gives you for IP-independent access to your site.

If you use a Dynamic IP service, then your router may be able to keep your IP up-to-date with the service; if not you will need to run the client that they provide to monitor your public IP periodically and update their server whenever there is a change.